# Execute test case step by step in testlink

Tags: unit-testing, testlink

I created the following testcase in testlink 1.9.7. The case has a summary, preconditions and six steps.

The section steps is this [image]

The trouble is that, I want to execute the test case step by step, and assign result and note/description for each step.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Test results and notes per step are possible since TestLink version 1.9.11.